# Vector space $U/V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ a vector space of dimension $n$ and $V\subsetneq U$ a subspace of dimension $m<n$. We define $$U/V:=\{u+V\mid u\in U\},$$
where $$u+V:=\{u+v\mid v\in V\}.$$

Define law $\bar +$ and $\bar \cdot $ on $U/V$ that make $(U/V,\bar +,\bar \cdot )$ is a vector space, and prove that $U/V$ has dimension $m-n$.

I defined $$(u+V)\bar +(w+V)=(u+w)+V\quad \text{and}\quad \alpha \bar \cdot (u+V)=\alpha u+V,$$
and I proved that $(U/V,\bar +,\bar \cdot )$ is a vector space. But I don't see how to prove that it has dimension $n-m$.

**Attempt**

Let $V=Span\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ and we prolonge it in a basis of $U$, i.e. $U=Span\{v_1,...,v_n\}$. Now, what is going to be a basis of $U/V$. I guess it will be $\{v_{m+1},...,v_{n}\}$, but how can I prove it ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

It should rather be $\{v_{m+1}+V,\cdots,v_n+V\}$. If $u+V\in U/V$, then $$u+V=\alpha _1v_1+...+\alpha _nv_n+V=\alpha _{m+1}\bar \cdot (v_{m+1}+V)\bar+\cdots \bar +\alpha _n\bar\cdot (v_n+V).$$
What remains to be proved is that $$\alpha _1\bar \cdot (v_{m+1}+V)\bar+\cdots \bar+\alpha _m\bar\cdot (v_n+V)=V\implies \alpha _i=0,$$
for all $i$.